# Grails-generated Hibernate Definitions

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Does Grails explicitly generate hibernate definitions of entities?

- If so where are these stored and are these annotation-based or XML based?
- If not, is there a ready-made tool to generate such Hibernate definitions?

This would enable us to make use of the tools that work from Hibernate entity definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Grails explicitly generate hibernate definitions of entities?

No, the domain classes are mapped to Hibernate programmatically by calling the Hibernate API. If you want more detail, the relevant source code [starts here](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4/src/main/groovy/org/grails/orm/hibernate/cfg/GrailsAnnotationConfiguration.java#L154).